# jquery in sharepoint 2013 web part

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, ascx

I am trying to add Jquery to a SharePoint 2013 Visual webpart.  I have put the script files in the layouts folder and I am able to reference them in my ascx, but it is not recognizing any jquery syntax.

```
<script src="../_layouts/15/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/15/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function () { $("#accordian").accordion(); });//not recognized
</script>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

When I try running it, I get Error: 'jQuery' is undefined.  When I debug, it is in the UI script file, so it looks like it is loading the jQuery-UI but not the main jQuery script. (Maybe?)

**EDIT**

Actual problem turned out to be my jQuery file was malformed.  **@Moderator - Please delete**

Comment: what is the error thrown in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to put your jQuery files in a specific folder in Layouts as to not clutter the Layouts directory.

And then you can simply reference your jQuery files like this:

```
<SharePoint:Scriptlink ID="jQuery" runat="server" Name="MyWebPart/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" Language="javascript" />
<SharePoint:Scriptlink ID="jQueryUI" runat="server" Name="MyWebPart/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js" Language="javascript" />
```

And so your files would be sitting in the following location on the server:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyWebPart\jquery-2.1.0.min.js`

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyWebPart\jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js`

Answer (score 2):

Do it like so

```
<link href="/_layouts/15/SBBJobBox/css/SBB/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/_layouts/15/SBBJobBox/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SBBJobBox/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is directly from my project. Of course you will use your version of jQ. Don't know why 2013 changed from 2010 on that.

Comment: Are you saying that my problem is with the .. in front of the / or that my jquery files are not in a sub folder of layouts?  Neither is working for me.

Comment: the .. for some reason the .. make VS happy but not SP.

Answer (score 1):

if the console shows above message in sharepoint.Instead of $(document).ready() function
use _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push();

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myFunctionName");//this function called during page load
function myCustomName(){
 alert('a');}
```

or it could be this

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(run, "sp.js");
function run(){j('#selector').method();}
```